# style a div element that is nested within a section in css

Tags: html, css

how to style a div element that is nested within a section, this is what I tried, but I get the error expecting "}";

```
#section1
{

    color: blue;

    #div1 {
        color: red;
      }

}
```

Comment: #section1 #div1{..}

Comment: If your div has the ID `div1` then `#div1` by itself should suffice. Would help to see your HTML

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use less or sass, you should not write nested classes.
the only thing that you can use is that divide your class into 2 classes:
But you also can only use #div 1 instead of #section1 #div1.

```css
#section1 {
    color: blue;
}

#section1 #div1 {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1">
   ABC
   <div id="div1">
     XYZ
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it have the id, you can select the ID directly:

```
#div1 {
    // your style here
}
```

or ou can use CSS selectors in conjunction with it's IDs:

```
div#section1 div#div1 {
    // your style here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using just css, then try like,

```
#section1
 {
color: blue;  
 }

  #section1 #div1 
    {
  color: red;
  }
```